# Highlight the Active Page when Children are Generated by Plugin

Tags: content-management-system, grav, grav-plugin

I'm in the process of writing a plugin for my website. It has a file for the top level file, but all of the child pages are generated by the plugin itself. This is mostly because the plugin has to deal with a database.

Currently my webpage is setup as `mysite.com/plugin_page`. This plugin page does in fact have an associated `.md` file. The plugin is able to generate child pages such as `mysite.com/plugin_page/view/$` and `mysite.com/plugin_page/new`.

When I'm viewing `mysite.com/plugin_page` the correct page is marked as active, so it's highlighted as I'd expect in the navbar. Once I go to a child page, however, no page is highlighted.

I want `mysite.com/plugin_page/view/$` to highlight it's parent page, just like a blog entry would have `blog` highlighted in the example themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the Grav source code I figured out the solution to this problem. It involves a couple steps.

**1. The route must be set**

If the page's route isn't set, the page will never return true when `active()` is called. Since no page ever returns true, the highlight never appears.

Example Code:

```php
$uri  = $this->grav['uri'];
$page = $this->grav['page'];

...

$page->route($uri->path());
```

**2. The page needs to be assigned to the appropriate parent page**

If the generated page isn't the parent page itself, you need to assign it to the appropriate parent.

Example Code:

```php
$pages        = $this->grav['pages'];
$parent_route = $this->config->get('plugins.myplugin.parent_route');
$page->parent($pages->find($parent_route));
```